# WebResource.axd 404

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webresource.axd

I have encountered a problem loading .css file using WebResource in ASP.NET Webform project. The project refers to a sharedProject folder. Every page in the project inherits from a common base page inside the sharedProject. Now I create a CommonStyle.css inside sharedProject and try to inject it into the base page.

Weird thing is that the WebResource with 404 error message has a type of "text/html". After I move the PageBase.cs into MyProject folder, the WebResource can then successfully load. I am so frustrated and confused right now. Please help.

Directory structure is as follows:

- SharedProject

  - CommonStyle.css
  - PageBase.cs
- MyProject

  - Webpage1
  - Webpage2
  - Webpage3

Code in PageBase.cs, OnInit function:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        HyperLink hlHelpFile = new HyperLink();
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
        Type rsType = typeof(PageBase);
        hlHelpFile.NavigateUrl = cs.GetWebResourceUrl(rsType, "Web.CommonStyle.css");
        this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(hlHelpFile);

        HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
        css.Href = hlHelpFile.NavigateUrl; 
        css.Attributes.Add("rel","stylesheet");
        css.Attributes.Add("type","text/css");
        css.Attributes.Add("media","all");
        this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);

        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

I have also added webResourceAttribute in AssemblyInfo.cs as follows:

```
[assembly: WebResourceAttribute("SharedProject.CommonStyle.css", "text/css")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've struggled so much but finally figured it out. The thing is I put assembly information in the wrong place. The WebResource assembly should always be put in the same project as the base page class (Shared Project).

I know this is a stupid mistake. I will put this here in case someone else is struggling at the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure max query string and maxurl size Big enough ;

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" maxUrl="760" maxQueryString="390" />
    <!--50MB-->
    <verbs>
      <add verb="TRACE" allowed="false" />
      <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="false" />
    </verbs>
  </requestFiltering>
  <isapiCgiRestriction notListedIsapisAllowed="false" />
</security>
```